# I have a jquery question,chould you help me?

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var $category = $("ul li:gt(5):not(:last)");
$category.hide();
$("input").click(function(){
if($category.is(":visiable")){
    $category.hide();
    $("input").attr("value","精简显示")
    }
    else{
    $category.show();
    $("input").attr("value","全部显示")
    }
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="category">
    <ul>
    <li>苹果</li>
    <li>诺基亚</li>
    <li>摩托罗拉</li>
    <li>索爱</li>
    <li>三星</li>
    <li>LG</li>
    <li>黑莓</li>
    <li>多普达</li>
    <li>西门子</li>
    <li>魅族</li>
    <li>其他品牌</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="more"><input type="button" value="全部显示"></div>
```

The code is error,but I don't know what wrong is,chould you help me?

Comment: you need to give us more information than `the code is error`

Comment: and it should be `$category.is(":visible")` instead of `$category.is(":visiable")`

Comment: i think it could be that you're missing a `;` in the penultimate `})`

Comment: Yes, we could, but you need to provide more info: what are you trying to achieve, how you think it should work, how it doesn't (what error)? btw, welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

probably the `$category.is(":visiable")` mispelled (should be `":visible"` without the 'a')

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $category = $("ul li:gt(5):not(:last)");
    $category.hide();
    $("input").click(function(){
        if($category.is(":visible")){ << corrected spelling ([@serge])
            $category.hide();
            $("input").attr("value","精简显示")
        }
        else{
            $category.show();
            $("input").attr("value","全部显示")
        }
    }); << added ;
});
```

Coded up on jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/9keby/